# Uncaught SyntaxError:Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var logged      =  "<?php echo $_SESSION['LoginValidation'] ?>"; // check loging or not for voting, favoriting and ...

$(document).ready(function(e) {

$(document).scroll(function () {
         var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y > 37) {
            $("#header").addClass("header_shadow");
              }

        else
             $("#header").removeClass("header_shadow");
        });

});

</script>
```

And it throws this error:

[image]

The image seems I'm missing semi-colon in the end of line, But as you see in the code, I've written it.

So what's the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: `LoginValidation` doesn't exists in `$_SESSION`. Try `print_r($_SESSION);` and check what all it has.

Comment: @MilanChheda yes, sometimes it doesn't exist. Do I need to check it first?

Comment: you should add condition for `LoginValidation` exists or not.

Comment: Have you tried console.log(err); at all and checked your console for any failures?

Comment: @SwitchCase The error is being generated by PHP, not JavaScript... The JS doesn't even get to run because it has spurious HTML and text in its code—the result of the PHP error output.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "Undefined index: LoginValidation", so you'll need to make sure it exists before referencing it. I don't know how you intend your code to work, but you can do something like:

```
var logged =  "<?php echo isset($_SESSION['LoginValidation']) 
                     ? $_SESSION['LoginValidation'] 
                     : ''; ?>";
```

This will use the value of `$_SESSION['LoginValidation']` if it exists, otherwise it will set an empty string ("").

Comment: This answer doesn't properly encode the data for use in a script.

Comment: @Brad, You downvoted me for that? I was answering his question and addressing his error. I don't know what he's doing with the data he wants to assign, so I don't know whether it is appropriate to encode it (I didn't even know whether the data was supposed to be there or not).

Comment: @wrlee Yep, I downvoted you for that.  You're taking an arbitrary PHP variable and injecting it into JavaScript.  `json_encode()` is **always** appropriate in this case.  Your answer is incomplete.  People copy/paste code all the time without any idea what they're doing.  Chances are, your code is going to end up broken very quickly.  On the worst case scenario, you're going to inject user data into a script making yet more insecure websites.  Your code is broken, and deserves a downvote until fixed.  Never put data into a new context without properly escaping it for that new context.

Comment: @Brad, I'm not trying to solve the world's problems nor assume too much about his business logic. I try to keep my answers clear, simple, and targeted. Using `json_encode` imposes assumptions about the definition & use of his data—and a whole context of discussion that he didn't ask for. Those who blindly cuts-pastes get what they deserve. Questioners are encouraged to simplify their question and example to get to the meat of their problem. I try to do the same in my answers. You make valid comments, but to down-vote an answer that's essentially correct (and not misleading) is pretty bold.

Comment: @wrlee Using `json_encode()` does the opposite of making assumptions.  It works with most any data.  Your answer makes a ton of assumptions about what's in that session variable, and is therefore wrong.  Voting on an answer on Stack Overflow is a basic part of this site... there's nothing bold about it, particularly when downvoting an answer that shows a blatantly dangerous method of injecting arbitrary data into JavaScript.  If you wanted to simplify your answer, you should have explained what `isset()` does and left it at that, rather than writing bad demonstration code.

Comment: @Brad This seems to be a discussion best taken outside the context of this q&a since our points have been repeatedly made. I'd be happy to debate this further with you, in a chat that exists here, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing semi-colon in **php tag** echo statement .

```
var logged= "<?php echo $_SESSION['LoginValidation'] ?>"
```

Just change

```
var logged= "<?php echo $_SESSION['LoginValidation']; ?>"
```

**Resolved**

Check the session has value or not first like

```
var logged= "<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['LoginValidation'])?$_SESSION['LoginValidation']:''); ?>"
```

It will work for you.

Comment: the same one . . .

Comment: $_SESSION['LoginValidation'] is present or not ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo The screenshot in the question says it's not.

Comment: @MartinAJ  same to u .

Comment: This answer doesn't properly encode the data for use in a script.

Answer (score 0):

If `$_SESSION['LoginValidation']` isn't always going to be present, you'll need to at least return `null` or something to assign to `logged`.

Fortunately for you, if you'd output this variable properly with `json_encode()` (which makes it compatible with JSON), this happens automagically!

```
var logged = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['LoginValidation']) ?>;
```

I'll leave it to you to decide how you want to handle when that variable isn't there.  You really should test for it (`isset()`, `!empty()`, etc.) so that you don't end up with warnings in your logs.  (Also, turn off warnings and error output in your output... dump them into logs instead.)

Comment: Firstly, you should wrap the PHP part of your code into `"`. Also the error is still there.

Comment: @MartinAJ No, you shouldn't.  Quotes, if required for the type, are output by `json_encode()`.  And, you should read the last paragraph of my answer.  I have no idea how you want to deal with the fact that the variable isn't set... that's up to you.

Comment: Honestly still I don't understand why should I use `json_encode`. It's not an ajax request. Thank you anyway. Upvote

Comment: @MartinAJ JSON syntax is compatible with JavaScript.  You're taking a PHP variable and injecting it into the context of a JavaScript script.  To do that, it has to be in the right syntax.  A naive approach would assume you're outputting a string, and would use static quotes around that string.  This will work up until the day that string has a quote mark in it.  Now what?  You've generated a syntax error.  What if the data type isn't a string, but a number?  Now you've converted your number to a string.  What if it's actually `null`?  You could output `null`...

Comment: @MartinAJ You can transfer strings, booleans, numbers, arrays, objects, and null by using `json_encode()`.  And, you can do this while guaranteeing that you're not going to destroy your script with invalid syntax.  By just echoing who knows what into quotes, you have no such guarantee.  The only guarantee you get there is that it's going to break some day.  All these other answers not using `json_encode()` are flat out wrong, and these folks' web pages are all likely broken in ways they don't know yet.